# How to dynamically set template roles signers "email" and "name" of a template using REST v2 API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm interested in getting roles signers from template and assign roles Signer email & Signer name for template signature request. Is this possible using REST v2 API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's definitely possible and easy to assign signers to template roles using their email and name.  Have you seen the DocuSign **API Walkthroughs** through the Developer Center?  They contain sample code written in 6 different languages for 9 common API scenarios, sending from a template being one of them.  You can find the walkthroughs through the API Tools page here:

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/api-explorer

For instance, here is the full C# version of the code.  Just replace the values for the variables at the top and run!  (Note you'll also have to create a template in your developer account and copy the `templateId` into the code too):

```
// DocuSign API Walkthrough 01 in C# - Request Signature from Template
//
// To run this sample: 
//  1) Create a new .NET project.
//  2) Add 4 assembly references to the project:  System, System.Net, System.XML, and System.XML.Linq
//  3) Update the email, password, integrator key, and template variables in the code
//  4) Compile and Run
//
// NOTE 1: This sample requires that you first create a Template through the DocuSign member Console.
//
// NOTE 2: The DocuSign REST API accepts both JSON and XML formatted http requests.  These C# API walkthroughs
//     demonstrate the use of XML format, whereas the other walkthroughs show examples in JSON format.
using System; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace DocuSignAPIWalkthrough01 
{
    public class RequestSignatureFromTemplate 
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // ENTER VALUES FOR THE FOLLOWING 7 VARIABLES:
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            string username = "***";        // your account email
            string password = "***";        // your account password
            string integratorKey = "***";       // your account Integrator Key (found on Preferences -> API page)
            string templateId = "***";      // valid templateId from a template in your account
            string templateRole = "***";        // template role that exists on above template
            string recipientName = "***";       // recipient (signer) name
            string recipientEmail = "***";      // recipient (signer) email
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            // additional variable declarations
            string baseURL = "";            // we will retrieve this through the Login API call

            try {
                //============================================================================
                //  STEP 1 - Login API Call (used to retrieve your baseUrl)
                //============================================================================

                // Endpoint for Login api call (in demo environment):
                string url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";

                // set request url, method, and headers.  No body needed for login api call
                HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest( url, "GET", null, username, password, integratorKey);

                // read the http response
                string response = getResponseBody(request);

                // parse baseUrl value from response body
                baseURL = parseDataFromResponse(response, "baseUrl");

                //--- display results
                Console.WriteLine("\nAPI Call Result: \n\n" + prettyPrintXml(response));

                //============================================================================
                //  STEP 2 - Send Signature Request from Template
                //============================================================================

                // append "/envelopes" to baseURL and use for signature request api call
                url = baseURL + "/envelopes";

                // construct an outgoing XML formatted request body (JSON also accepted)
                string requestBody = 
                    "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                        "<status>sent</status>" + 
                        "<emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request from Template</emailSubject>" +
                        "<templateId>" + templateId + "</templateId>" + 
                        "<templateRoles>" + 
                            "<templateRole>" + 
                                "<name>" + recipientName + "</name>" +
                                "<email>" + recipientEmail + "</email>" +   
                                "<roleName>" + templateRole + "</roleName>" + 
                            "</templateRole>" + 
                        "</templateRoles>" + 
                    "</envelopeDefinition>";

                // set request url, method, body, and headers
                request = initializeRequest( url, "POST", requestBody, username, password, integratorKey);

                // read the http response
                response = getResponseBody(request);

                //--- display results
                Console.WriteLine("\nAPI Call Result: \n\n" + prettyPrintXml(response));
            }
            catch (WebException e) {
                using (WebResponse response = e.Response) {
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                    Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                    using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(prettyPrintXml(text));
                    }
                }
            }
        } // end main()

        //***********************************************************************************************
        // --- HELPER FUNCTIONS ---
        //***********************************************************************************************
        public static HttpWebRequest initializeRequest(string url, string method, string body, string email, string password, string intKey)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (url);
            request.Method = method;
            addRequestHeaders( request, email, password, intKey );
            if( body != null )
                addRequestBody(request, body);
            return request;
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static void addRequestHeaders(HttpWebRequest request, string email, string password, string intKey)
        {
            // authentication header can be in JSON or XML format.  XML used for this walkthrough:
            string authenticateStr = 
                "<DocuSignCredentials>" + 
                    "<Username>" + email + "</Username>" +
                    "<Password>" + password + "</Password>" + 
                    "<IntegratorKey>" + intKey + "</IntegratorKey>" +
                    "</DocuSignCredentials>";
            request.Headers.Add ("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authenticateStr);
            request.Accept = "application/xml";
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static void addRequestBody(HttpWebRequest request, string requestBody)
        {
            // create byte array out of request body and add to the request object
            byte[] body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (requestBody);
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
            dataStream.Write (body, 0, requestBody.Length);
            dataStream.Close ();
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static string getResponseBody(HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            // read the response stream into a local string
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return responseText;
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static string parseDataFromResponse(string response, string searchToken)
        {
            // look for "searchToken" in the response body and parse its value
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(response))) {
                while (reader.Read()) {
                    if((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == searchToken))
                        return reader.ReadString();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static string prettyPrintXml(string xml)
        {
            // print nicely formatted xml
            try {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                return doc.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception) {
                return xml;
            }
        }
    } // end class
} // end namespace
```